# Getting error column does not exist error in postgress

Tags: postgresql

My query is

```
<...>

If role_cd != rolecd THEN 
    UPDATE schema.user SET user.role_cd = rolecd Where user.id = id;
END IF;

<...>
```

What should be the issue

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link) and show us the complete code of your stored function or procedure

Comment: That's not SQL. You need to give more context, like the programming language and the definition of the table. Also, the complete error message. The database management system is called "PostgreSQL".

Comment: From docs [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html): *Do not include the table's name in the specification of a target column — for example, UPDATE table_name SET table_name.col = 1 is invalid.*